# When does it make sense to use @@IDENTITY and not SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Tags: sql-server

According to MSDN, `@@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.`

Has anyone come across a situation where this functionality was useful? I can't think of a situation when you would want the last ID generated for any table across all scopes or how you would use it.

UPDATE:

Not sure what all the downvotes are about, but I figured I'd try to clarify what I'm asking.

First off I know when to use SCOPE_IDENTITY and IDENT_CURRENT.  What I'm wondering is when would it be better to use @@IDENTITY as opposed to these other options?  I have yet to find a place to use it in my day to day work and I'm wondering if someone can describe a situation when it is the best option.

Most of the time when I see it, it is because someone doesn't understand what they were doing, but I assume Microsoft included it for a reason.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that you want to know why someone would use @@IDENTITY and not SCOPE_INDENTITY() or IDENT_CURRENT() - I assume that is a the question.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in my comment, but I think I missed a word or two from the sentence.

Comment: @DaveShaw, yeah I think we're on the same page.  I updated my question.

Comment: LOL - would you accept an answer of "By Mistake". I see developers use it by mistake all the time ;)

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` may be a good seed for getting random numbers.  The `OUTPUT` clause has some advantages: it works when multiple rows are inserted and it works.  See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it shouldn't be used. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is far safer to use (as long as we're talking about single-row inserts, as highlighted in a comment above), *except* in the following scenario, where `@@IDENTITY` is one approach that can be used (`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` cannot in this case):

- your code knowingly fires a trigger
- the trigger inserts into a table with an identity column
- the calling code needs the identity value generated inside the trigger
- the calling code can guarantee that the `@@IDENTITY` value generated within the trigger will never be changed to reflect a different table (e.g. someone adds logging to the trigger *after* the insert you were relying on)

This is an odd use case, but feasible.

Keep in mind this won't work if you are inserting multiple rows and need multiple `IDENTITY` values back. There are other ways, but they also require the option to allow result sets from cursors, and IIRC this option is being deprecated.

Comment: I'm aware that in most cases it shouldn't be used.  Are you saying that @@IDENTITY is BETTER to use in those situations, or just that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` isn't necessarily safer in those situations.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I'm saying that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` won't get the answer you want in the situation I describe in my answer, because it can't see the `IDENTITY` value generated by the insert inside the trigger, which happened on a different table.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Also to be clear that set of bullets is describing ONE situation, not multiple situations, where `@@IDENTITY` is a better answer than `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. My point is that there are use cases for `@@IDENTITY`, they're just few and far between.

Answer (score -2):

@@IDENTITY is fantastic for identifying individual rows based on an ID column.

```
ID | Name | Age
1    AA     20
2    AB     30 
etc...
```

In this case the ID column would be reliant on the @@IDENTITY property.

Comment: Why @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which one would be the an advantage over the other.  @@IDENTITY has been working fine for my purposes thus far, but I have noticed that if some rows have been removed previously, the ID still increments.  Maybe the following link may provide further infromation on the difference:  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/